# Is it possible to decrypt cypher by signing from metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask, cryptography

The idea is to encrypt the message with the user's public key. Then user receives the encrypted message and needs to decrypt having metamask wallet connected. But we cannot get the user's private key from the connected metamask wallet. So, general approach of encrypting with public key and decrypting with private key won't work.

So, is there a way to encrypt the message publicly such that it gets decrypted when user sings the encrypted message from the metamask wallet ??

Answer (score 1):

> So, is there a way to encrypt the message publicly such that it gets decrypted when user sings the encrypted message from the metamask wallet ??

There is not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Metamask supports that kind of two-way signing. Maybe some other wallet does, but I kinda doubt it, since that's not a common use case.